# a surface plotting with inner and outer color different

Tags: matlab, plot

I am going to plot a 3D surface in matlab. I use the `surf` function, but I want to recolor it in a way that the inner surface has one color and the outer has another one. How can I do that?

```
A = [12 18 12
     23 47 27
     32 11 36
     48 47 39
     28 50 28]
figure, surf(A)
```

Comment: What do you mean by inner and outer? Up and down?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See if this helps,

```
 surf(A+.01,'FaceColor',[ 1  0  1]);
 hold on; 
 surf(A,'FaceColor',[ 0  0  1]);
```

gives,

[image]

[image]

I couldn't come up with better idea!

This is just a trick, maybe there is a way to color each side of a plane.

Comment: thanks, It is what I want, How can I change the colors?

Comment: just change the numbers, [1 0 0] is `red`, [0 1 0] is `green` ,... values must be in the interval of [0 1].

Comment: I havent tried, but what about even a smaller number for the uper srface? Idealy it should be something like `A+eps` rigth?

Comment: @AnderBiguri, for small shifts in `A` it seems that the plot can't handle it well, and you see the other surface from some angles. Ideally you are right, it should work.

Comment: Did you tried this in a matlab version older than 2014b? Im jut curious about the new figure handle.

Comment: @AnderBiguri, Yes mine is `2012a` and the figure is `A` and `A+1`.

Comment: Yep, no much better improvement is shown in `2014b`. With A+.01 you cannot see the gap between surfaces, but sometimes some edge is not drawn. Else works quite nice